# Select from stored procedure and show in ListView

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, android-activity

I recently want to select column from SQL Server stored procedure. Before I select from tables and it goes well.

My previous code read data from table and showed in ListView very well.

Here is my previous query and code :

```
try {
    ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
    statement = connectionHelper.getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select Name from Car");
```

and after that I showed it in ListView

```
driver = resultSet.getString(resultSet.findColumn("DriverName"));
myList.add(driverName);
```

Now we have a stored procedure (`SpGetReadyDairyLoading`) that returns all value and `DriverName` value.

I want to select `DriverName` from that (when I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, it returns the `DriverName` and some other columns)

How can I do this? I googled a lot but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Stored Procedure select from a table, with none parameter.
So i have to use a CallableStatement.

```
CallableStatement catCallable;
ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
catCallable = connectionHelper.getConnection().prepareCall("{ CALL SpGetDairyCategory}"); //call my storedprocedure with nonparameter
catCallable.execute(); //execute storedprocedure
ResultSet resultSet = catCallable.getResultSet(); return the result to resultset
```